# Making async calls inside Jasmine it() function

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm getting some hard time trying to figure out how can I do an async call inside the `it` function. I tried this, but always fails.

```
var i = 0;
it("Test async", function(done) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    i = 1;
    done();
  }, 1000);
  expect(i).toEqual(1);  // Fails. 0 expected to equal 1.
})
```

It is possible?

Comment: Can't the `expect` call go inside the async function just before `done();`?

Comment: @Whymarrh I tried that, but not it does not work neither.